# Cypress - How to do polling in Cypress?

Tags: cypress, ui-automation, long-polling

On web application, particular element is visible only after page reload and that is also available after some time, so currently I have implemented it as below:

```
it('element-check', () => {
    cy.visit('url')
// performing certain actions 
    cy.wait(150000)
    cy.reload()
    cy.contains('text').click()
})
```

instead of fixed wait cy.wait(150000), I need to use the polling mechanism in such a way that after every 30 seconds the page is getting reloaded and check for the required element until the element is visible.

Comment: Check cypress-wait-until plugin, sounds like it would be perfect for your case. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to achieve this.

```
it('element-check', () => {
  cy.visit('url')

  let retry = 0
  function isElementVisible() {
    
    if (retry < 5 && Cypress.$('selector').length == 0) {

      //Increment retry
      retry++

      //wait 30 seconds
      cy.wait(30000)

      //Reload Page
      cy.reload()

      //Element is not yet visible, Call the recursive function again
      cy.then(isElementVisible)

    } else if (retry < 5 && Cypress.$('selector').length == 1) {
      cy.get('selector').click()
      return

    } else {
      //It excedded required no. of execution
      return
    }
  }
  //Trigger the recursive function
  cy.then(isElementVisible)
})
```

Comment: Unbounded recursion is bad practice.

Comment: Yes true, I missed that. Updated my answer. Now the function will retry a finite number of times to find the element before completely exiting.

Comment: 1 thing `.then ` cant be chained of a `cy`, according to https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html#Differences . I would chain it of a `cy.log()` to know when the function has started, or directly call it `isElementVisible()`. Also a `cy.wait()` in the beginning of a recursion seems bad for me. I would put it at the end if needed.

Comment: @RosenMihaylov The OP wanted to reload the page after every 30 seconds. I was wondering, how else it could have been achieved ?

Comment: I would just put it in the else statement, after the page check

Comment: Sorry my bad - not in the else but in the first check that sees no element - before invoking the recursion. Also i would reduce the wait time to ne 10 seconds and make the recursion up to 15 times, because 30 seconds seems too much of a fixed wait.

Comment: The times and retry are variable. One can adjust it as per their needs. The OP mentioned 30 seconds hence I wrote 30.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224797/discussion-between-rosen-mihaylov-and-alapan-das).